# database connection by an application

Tags: oracle

How to to know how many connection established by an application to a database(Oracle). I have java web application connection to a oracle database. Just want to know how may connections are open to db when the application is running.

Comment: check v$session view in your database for list of active sessions

Answer (score 1):

You can see the number of currently active sessions through querying the `V$SESSION` table:

```
SELECT * FROM V$SESSION
```

You could then filter for specific users/programs to check how many parallel connections have been openend, i.e.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM V$SESSION WHERE program = 'executablename.exe';");

rs.next();
count = rs.getInt("cnt");
```